# Ceuta to Tangier by foot and train?

Tags: public-transport, hiking, morocco, tangier

This question consists of two parts:

**Is it possible to walk from Ceuta to Tanger Med along the coast?**

There seem to be roads and/or beaches along some of the Moroccan coastline, but not all of it – are there any continuous paths at or near the rest of the coastline?

**Is the Trains navettes rapides line between Tanger Med and Tanger Ville in operation?**

The rail line is included in the [official railway map](https://www.oncf.ma/fr/content/download/39044/892784/file/Legende%20et%20Carte%20Ferroviaire%20Valable%20%C3%A0%20partir%20%2017-12-2018.pdf), yet there are no schedules for it on the ONCF website and the ONCF trip planner shows no connections between Tanger Med and Tanger Ville despite knowing both stations.